# how to set particular script file global in MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am working on MVC project I have one jquery script which used all web pages of website project. I want Set it globally can you guys help me????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your script in `_Layout.cshtml` page.

In MVC it's better to use bundles for this case.

In your `App_Start\BundleConfig.cs`:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/global").Include(
  "~/Scripts/yourGlobalScript.js"));
```

In your `Views\Shared\_Layout` page:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/global")
```